# How to send arguments to Ruby program

Tags: ruby, rake

I tried this code in order to send arguments to Ruby program:

```
namespace :tnx do

  require_relative "transactions.rb"
  include Cnp_transactions_modes

  task :generate, [:clean_all] => [:environment]  do |t, args|

    if args[: clean_all] == 'true'
      // something
    end

    if args[:times]
      Cnp_transactions_modes.create_tnx(args[:times])
    else 
     puts "\nSet some number\n"
    end    
  end
end
```

When I run the code this way:

```
bundle exec rake test:generate['true','30']
```

I get `Set some number`

Can you give some advice how I can fix the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring like this

```
task :generate, [:clean_all, :times] => [:environment]  do |t, args|
```

and calling like this

```
bundle exec rake tnx:generate['true','30']
```

Comment: I get NoMethodError: undefined method `times' for "30":String

Comment: Try bundle exec rake tnx:generate['true',30]

Comment: I get NoMethodError: undefined method `times' for "30":String

Comment: even after removing the quotes around 30?

Comment: Yes, can you show me the some better way how I can refractor the code?

Comment: `Cnp_transactions_modes.create_tnx(args[:times].to_i)` can you try this

Comment: Now I get NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Congrats! you have confused yourself with the previous answer by Eric and confused my answer with it and somehow did update your editor, but updated the question.

Comment: Arguments are always strings, just like [`gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) returns the input as a string. Call it via `rake tnx:generate[true,30]` (i.e. without quotes) and convert the arguments within the rake task.

Comment: @gates: Ahah. I  also got confused. I've looked at this question and asked myself : "Wait, where's my answer?" :)

Comment: So where is your answer Eric :)?